# Resultado 0.0 - mesmo com typecast ou trocando tipos das variáveis

Tags: java, array, double

Tenho esse método na classe secundária para calcular a mediana de um vetor:

```
public class Funcoes {
....
 public void setMediana(int[] valores) {

        double med;

        Arrays.sort(valores);
        int meio = valores.length / 2;
        if (valores.length % 2 == 0) {
            int esquerda = valores[meio - 1];
            int direita = valores[meio];
            med = (double) (esquerda + direita) / 2;
        } else {
            med = (double) valores[meio];
        }

        this.mediana = med;
}
    public double getMediana() {
        return mediana;
}
```

E essa é a minha classe principal:

```
{
public class EstatisticaX3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] valores = {56, 61, 57, 77, 62, 75, 63, 55, 64, 60, 60, 57, 61, 57, 67, 62, 69, 67, 68, 59, 65,
            72, 65, 61, 68, 73, 65, 62, 75, 80, 66, 61, 69, 76, 72, 57, 75, 68, 83, 64, 69, 64, 66, 74,
            65, 76, 65, 58, 65, 64, 65, 60, 65, 80, 66, 80, 68, 55, 66, 71};

        Funcoes exemplo01 = new Funcoes(valores);

        System.out.println(exemplo01.getMedia());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(exemplo01.setFrequenciaOrdem(valores));
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(exemplo01.getMediana()); */aqui que o resultado é 0.0*

    }
}
```

Tentei usar a variável med como inteiro e dar typecast, tentei mudando as outras variáveis também, apesar de eu achar que esse jeito acima seria o correto e mesmo assim só dá 0.0

Comment: O problema está em `med = (double) (esquerda + direta)/2`, certo? Isso acontece pois o `cast` ocorre na divisão, não no numerador. Divida por `2.0` eu faça o cast no numerador: `med = ((double) esquerda+direita)/2`

Comment: Ok, eu pensei que o erro era no cálculo, mas pelo visto é no ciclo de vida das variáveis. Por que você tem um `set` que não é chamado? E por que guardar o valor de um atributo derivado?

Comment: É verdade, ainda estou aprendendo a usar getters e setters, meu erro foi nessa parte mesmo. Deletei o get e usei o set direto e deu certo. Valeu de qualquer forma!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce não está chamando o método `setMediana` portanto o resultado é o valor inicial da variável `mediana`, ou seja, `0.0`.

Tente algo como

```
System.out.println(" ");
exemplo01.setMediana(valores);
System.out.println(exemplo01.getMediana());
```

*(não testado)*

está meio confuso, eu faria um único método `calcularMediana` em vez do `setMediana` e `getMediana`

Comment: Fiz desse jeito mesmo e deu certo! Valeu!

Comment: @LuisFernando , a melhor forma de agradecer é marcando essa resposta como a aceita

Comment: Opa blz, estou aprendendo a usar o stack agora!